# How to open port in client side in windows using my own pptp vpn server on linux?

Tags: port, port-forwarding, pptp, pptpd, pptp-client

I had been setup my own `pptpd` server in my vultr ubuntu server and i connect on it using my client built in in windows and i success to access the internet and when i check my ip i see the vps ip instead of my real ip, but my problem is when i try to open port in my windows client using simple tool called `portlistener` and start listening to port 80 i went to checkport tool but i see the port 80 is closed. So does anyone know how to use this port on my client side?

my `ifconfig` command show this:

```
root@vultr:~# ifconfig
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 104.238.191.125  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 104.238.191.255
        inet6 fe80::5400:2ff:feec:61e8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 56:00:02:ec:61:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3383  bytes 984017 (960.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3470  bytes 897643 (876.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens7: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.24.96.3  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.24.255.255
        inet6 fe80::5800:2ff:feec:61e8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5a:00:02:ec:61:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 370 (370.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 225  bytes 9910 (9.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1396
        inet 10.24.96.3  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.24.96.5
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 340  bytes 45323 (44.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 183  bytes 47486 (46.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`iptables -L` command show:

```
root@vultr:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     gre  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1723 state NEW

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
TCPMSS     tcp  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here:

[Port forwarding for iptables (DMZ)](https://debian-administration.org/article/73/Port_forwarding_for_iptables_DMZ)

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.50:80
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 80 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```